# C# Interface method not saving in .dll, is not member of interface

Tags: c#

I keep receiving a "is not member of interface" for a method that I put in an interface, see code below:

```
public interface IDepartmentDataSource
{
    IQueryable<Employee> Employees { get; }
    IQueryable<Department> Departments { get; }
    void Save();
}
```

Then I implement the interface and use it like this,

```
    void IDepartmentDataSource.Save()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }
```

This is when I get the error, I can see the Employees and Departments, but not the save. When I go to the metadata for the definition, I do not see the Void Save() in there either, But it is in my Interface file.

Can someone shed a little light, thanks.

UPDATE:: This is what I see when I say navigate to definition, even if I delete the .dll and rebuild, I receive the same thing.

```
#region Assembly eManager.Domain.dll, v1.0.0.0
// C:\PluralSight\eManager\eManager.Web\bin\eManager.Domain.dll
#endregion

using System.Linq;

namespace eManager.Domain
{
    public interface IDepartmentDataSource
    {
        IQueryable<Department> Departments { get; }
        IQueryable<Employee> Employees { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obvious guess - did you try clean/rebuild?

Comment: yes, remove old reference did a build and added it in. But same results.

Comment: Are you sure there is only one type named `IDepartmentDataSource` around?

Comment: You should implement Save implicitly, otherwise you need to cast your class to a IDepartmentDataSource type to access the member.

Comment: it seems to be targeting different dll, given he edit (looks familiar but can't recall exactly, could be different things) - maybe something with the configuration, what's your target .NET (in both). Change something else, I don't know, naming to confirm that. Then try to localize the issue. Try building a new small project with only relevant parts, you'll soon see the problem

Comment: NSGaga, I think you are correct. In my obj/bin folder I deleted the temp files and also the .dlls there, cleaned and rebuild. Now I am back  in business

Comment: jpavlov good to hear that - you should close this then, put an answer yourself or let me know to copy/paste my comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try implementing the feature implicitly rather than explictly, otherwise you will only see it when your object is cast to IDepartmentDataSource:

```
public interface IDepartmentDataSource
{
    IQueryable<Employee> Employees { get; }
    IQueryable<Department> Departments { get; }
    void Save();
}

public class TestClass : IDepartmentDataSource
{
    public IQueryable<Employee> Employees
    {
        get { /* TODO: */}
    }

    public IQueryable<Department> Departments
    {
        get { /* TODO:  */ }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        //TODO:
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of NSGaga, I looked into my configuration and project setup, it became clear that this wasn't a code problem, but a problem with Visual Studio referencing a different .dll. My solution to this was the quick and dirty approach, and should only be used to get things moving along. The .dll that was being called was coming from the obj folder which would not update for any given reason, also, they were some temporary generated files that were in tack. I simply deleted these, knowing that they would be generated on next build and then got it running.

Thanks for the insight NSGaga!